# Python: re.sub return illegal characters when the source containing Chinese character

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have a text file that containing a pattern `[Chinese character]\nRT Journal`, and I want to identify this pattern, and substitute it to `[The original Chinese character]\n\nRT Journal`. I tried the code below but [The original Chinese character] becomes a unicode \x01.

```py
import re
x = "据\nRT Journal"
print(re.sub('([\u4e00-\u9fff])\nRT','\1\n\nRT',x))
```

It returns `'\x01\n\nRT Journal'` rather than `'据\n\nRT Journal'`. But if I replace the `据` in `x` with an `a`, I can get what I want. Can you please explain to me a bit why does this happen and how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: `'\1'` != `'\\1'`. You may use `'\\1\n\nRT'`

Comment: Or use a raw string `r'\1\n\nRT'` which is recommended for regular expressions in Python.